# How to extract all values of an indexed parameter/variable at once in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo

I know how to extract a value from a scalar parameter in pyomo.  However, I do not understand why an indexed parameter requires so much extra effort to extract all of the values at once (same goes for data initialization).

I looked in the source code but I could not find an obvious reason why this is the case.  Here's a comparison of the way things work, and the way I would have expected them to work:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

# How things work
model = pe.ConcreteModel()

def x_init(m, i):
    x = np.ones(2)
    return x[i]

model.del_component('x')
model.add_component('x', pe.Param(range(2), mutable=True, initialize=x_init))

def extract_values(m, i):
    x_ix = pe.value(m.x[i])
    return x_ix

x_value = [extract_values(model, i) for i in range(2)]
```

The above is very verbose in two ways:

- extracting values from the parameter
- initializing values for the indexed parameter

```
# How I wish things worked (much less verbose)
model = pe.ConcreteModel()

model.del_component('x')
model.add_component('x', pe.Param(range(2), mutable=True, initialize=np.ones(2)))

x_value = pe.value(m.x)
```

Is there an easier way to initialize and extract the values from an indexed parameter in pyomo?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447714/how-to-check-which-are-the-indexes-of-a-pyomo-variable

Answer (score 1):

Iwas not aware that it was that hard to initialize or retrieve values for `Param` or `Var` in pyomo. In my opinion it is easy, but I understand your problem. I think that this logic under the component creation is due de fact that `indexes` may be numeric, strings, etc... therefore, you can't initialize an `IndexedComponent` with a list, since you do not know which value belongs to which index. For instance, suposse that you have a `Param` indexed by `["New York", "Bogotá", "Lima"]`. You can assume that if you `initialize` the `Param` with `[10,3,1.5]` you mean that for `"New York"=10`, `"Bogotá"=3` and `"Lima"=1.5`, but it is better to be explicit about that, then, instead of a list, you can use a `dict`: `new_param = {"New York": 10, "Bogotá":3, "Lima":1.5}`

For me, it is easier to first create a `Set` (or several `Set`s if it is needed) and then populate all `Param`s and `Var`s.

```
import numpy as np
import pyomo.environ as pyo
k_init = np.ones(2)
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.k_set = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(k_init)))
#Create the Var
model.x = pyo.Var(model.k_set, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
#Create a param
model.k = pyo.Param(model.k_set, domain=pyo.Reals, initialize={k:v for k,v in enumerate(k_init)})

#Retrieving the values of k
for k,v in model.k.items():
    print(f'Param k[{k}]={v}')
```

This yields:

```
Param k[0]=1.0
Param k[1]=1.0
```

This is for `pyomo.environ` namespace. If you want to use `pyomo.kernel` space, you can use `variable_list` to avoid this behavior

Comment: Yes, that method works.  However, don't you agree that `initialize={k:v for k,v in enumerate(k_init)}` is still pretty verbose rather than `initialize=np.ones(2)`?  

Same for retrieving the values.  What you have there is only one line less than the `extract_values` method that I showed.

Comment: I agree that it may be verbose, but what you propose ignore the possibility of use non-sorted indexes for creating a `Param`. for  retrieving values you can even use `model.k.values()`, which return a `generator` for values. Again, as I said, in the `kernel` namespace, you can use `pyomo.kernel.parameter_list()`, but you still need to populate it with `pyomo.kernel.parameter`